# What's the structure of glibc's source code

Tags: c, linux

I tried to look for a specific function, e.g fstatfs, but I found the following code, it does almost nothing, I checked __set_errno macro, it's merely setting error number.

```
int
__fstatfs (int fd, struct statfs *buf)
{
  __set_errno (ENOSYS);
  return -1;
}
```

So a set of core library are implemented in ASM, but how is that working, if so why does these weak function even exist ?

Comment: So that you can call them from C?

Comment: According to man fstatfs a return code of ENOSYS means that call is not supported by that filesystem. Try to find another filesystem source.

Comment: @tinman a lot of other functions, e.g __connect, __listen are doing the same code..I just don't understand the architecture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that the call is OS-dependent, so what you're seeing is just a stub. There seems to be some kind of alias in [io/sys/statfs.h](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=io/sys/statfs.h;h=9e9f0944dbfc35fec2db35099ad33dcaae739d09;hb=ee9247c38a8def24a59eb5cfb7196a98bef8cfdc), and a candidate for the Linux implementation is in [sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fstatfs64.c](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fstatfs64.c;h=eed58cb5c26c4a22e878bf1ab3b11e3ea56aaee9;hb=ee9247c38a8def24a59eb5cfb7196a98bef8cfdc) file.

Comment: yeah, it should be like that, I'll take deeper look, thanks !

Comment: Quite right, che. Most of the C library functions in unistd.h are actually provided by the OS kernel, and the C library implementations are just wrappers around the kernel syscalls.